# Alternative to git rebase on public branches

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have read that a public branch should never be rebased. If that's not the case, what else should be done with it? Does it have to be merged each time and then recreated?

Comment: Merging a branch doesn't delete it. You can continue working on a branch and merge a branch as many times as you like

Answer (score 0):

It's very nice to uplift a public branch by merging it with whatever branch it's tracking. This of course gives you merge commits on the branch but it makes it very clear in the branch history when it was uplifted and what was added in between the uplifts.

It also works very well with gerrit if you're using that. A trivial uplift gives you an empty review window in gerrit.

Comment: so instead of rebasing it you would simply merge it and then continue to work on the branch?

Comment: yes exactly, it works better than rebasing in my opinion